# Changed form value does not display on return. Is there a binding problem between Thymeleaf and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

See this thymeleaf snippet in the form:

```
<form id="onlineRegistrationForm" action="#"
       th:action="@{/__${someId}__/registration}" th:object="${onlineRegistrationForm}"
       method="post" novalidate class="needs-custom-validation">
     ...
    <div class="form-group">
         <label th:for="__${personInstance}__.city" th:text="#{label.city}">city</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control basicAutoComplete"
                th:id="__${personInstance}__.city"
                aria-describedby="cityHelp" autocomplete="off"
                th:placeholder="#{label.city.ph}"
                th:field="*{__${personInstance}__.city}"
                th:attr="data-noresults-text='__#{search.nf}__'"
                th:attrappend="data-url='/__${someId}__/city/like'"
                th:errorclass="is-invalid">
         <small id="cityHelp" class="form-text text-muted"
                th:unless="${#fields.hasErrors('__${personInstance}__.city')}"
                th:text="#{label.city.tt}">city</small>
         <small id="cityError" class="invalid-feedback"
                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('__${personInstance}__.city')}"
                th:errors="*{__${personInstance}__.city}">Errors</small>
     </div>
```

Consider this POST - from a thymeleaf page:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/{someId}/apply")
        public String submitRegistration(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "onlineRegistrationForm") OnlineRegistrationForm onlineRegistrationForm,
                                         BindingResult bindingResult,
                                         @PathVariable String someId,
                                         Model model,
                                         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
                throws OnlineRegistrationRuntimeException {
   ...    
            validateOnlineRegistration(s, onlineRegistrationForm, bindingResult);
   ...
                if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("onlineRegistrationForm", messageSource.getMessage("error.message", new Object[]{""}, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())));
                return "apply";
            }
   ...
```

Within `validateOnlineRegistration`, I change some field, say `city` - because I determined it thru the postal code.
I tracked down this change until into the response message. It's there.

I mean, having the `BindingResult` directly after the `@Valid@Modelattribute`,
spring gives me control in the `@Controller`, so why the heck is the change not displayed on the result page?

Comment: Does your question concern  posting form with or without validation errors? If there are errors you returns `"apply"`. What do you return otherwise?

Comment: when errors occur, I return to "apply", otherwise I redirect to a success page.

Comment: Well... my guess is that `__${personInstance}__` is resolved to a field name referencing wrong instance - other than the one with modified `city`. Otherwise it looks decent.